# How to disable dates in datepicker form database?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "dates.php",
              success: function(data) { 
                 var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                 var date = '"' 
                 $.each(obj, function() {
                      date = date + this['date'] + '","';
                     });
                     date = date + '"';

                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                beforeShowDay: checkAvailability,

                            });
                        });

    var $myBadDates = new Array(date);

                        function checkAvailability(mydate){
                        var $return=true;
                        var $returnclass ="available";
                        $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', mydate);
                        for(var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++)
                            {    
                               if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
                                  {
                                $return = false;
                                $returnclass= "unavailable";
                                }
                            }
                        return [$return,$returnclass];
                        }
              }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

This is my existing code. I just want to disable some dates in datepicker coming from database.

`$myBadDates` takes array of dates like this "2017-05-01", "2017-05-02" which is coming in var date. But for some reason it is not working. When I put hand-written dates in `$myBadDates` it works well, but with var date it is not working.

I am unable to understand what is happening here as I am new to JavaScript and JSON.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your existing code?

Comment: above is my existing code. i just want to disable some dates in datepicker coming from database.
$myBadDates takes array of dates like this "2017-05-01","2017-05-02".which is coming in var date. but for some reason it is not working.when i put hand written dates in $myBadDates it works well. but with var date it is not working .plz help me. i am unable to understand what is happening here as i am new to javascript and json.

Answer (score 2):

Changing one array into another is done using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control):

```
var result = input.map(function(e) { return e.date; });
```

ES6:

```
var result = input.map(e => e.date);
```

```js
var input = [{"date":"2017-05-01"},{"date":"2017-04-10"},{"date":"2017-05-02"},{"date":"2017-04-30"},{"date":"2017-04-29"},{"date":"2017-04-28"},{"date":"2017-04-27"},{"date":"2017-04-26"},{"date":"2017-04-25"},{"date":"2017-04-24"},{"date":"2017-04-23"},{"date":"2017-04-14"},{"date":"2017-04-20"},{"date":"2017-05-03"},{"date":"2017-04-22"},{"date":"2017-04-21"},{"date":"2017-05-04"},{"date":"2017-04-19"},{"date":"2017-04-18"},{"date":"2017-04-17"},{"date":"2017-04-16"},{"date":"2017-04-11"},{"date":"2017-04-15"},{"date":"2017-05-05"},{"date":"2017-04-13"},{"date":"2017-04-12"},{"date":"2017-04-09"},{"date":"2017-04-08"},{"date":"2017-04-07"},{"date":"2017-04-06"},{"date":"2017-04-05"},{"date":"2017-04-04"},{"date":"2017-04-03"},{"date":"2017-04-02"},{"date":"2017-04-01"},{"date":"2017-03-31"},{"date":"2017-03-30"},{"date":"2017-02-07"},{"date":"2017-03-29"},{"date":"2017-03-28"},{"date":"2017-03-27"},{"date":"2017-02-08"},{"date":"2017-03-26"},{"date":"2017-03-25"},{"date":"2017-03-24"},{"date":"2017-03-23"},{"date":"2017-03-22"},{"date":"2017-03-21"},{"date":"2017-03-20"},{"date":"2017-02-28"}];

var output = input.map(function(e){ return e.date; });
console.log(output);
```